# Implementation of a step-scoped in-memory destination in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a requirement when using spring batch for the creation for a large report, in binary format, which is held in a database. None of the working data can be written directly to files, or to working tables outside the `JobExecutionContext`.

I'm aware that normally you would just write to the job execution context, but I'm a little confused as to how I would go about it with such a large report (potentially several hundred megabytes.)

At the moment, my `Writer` implementation has a dependency on an aggregator class, which is injected as a bean, then there's a TaskLet that has the aggregator injected in which writes the finished report to the database.

The problem is that I cannot scope my aggregator to the `step` context and as such if two jobs are running at the same time they will be writing to the same aggregator.

Here is my current implementation

### Domain class

```
public class DataChunk {
    private int pageNumber;
    private byte[] data;
}
```

### Writer

```
public class FooWriter implements ItemWriter<DataChunk> {

    private DataChunkAggregator dataChunkAggregator;

    public void write(List<? extends DataChunk> dataChunks) throws Exception {
        dataChunks.stream().forEach(chunk -> dataChunkAggregator.addChunk(chunk.getPageNumber(), chunk.getData()));
    }
}
```

### Aggregator

```
public class FooAggregator {
    private Map<int, byte> pagedData; // Key sorted implementation

    public void addChunk(int pageNumber, byte[] data) {
        pagedData.put(pageNumber, data)
    }

    public byte[] aggregate() {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        pagedData.values.stream().forEach(data -> baos.write(data));
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

### Report Writing Tasklet

```
public class ReportWritingTasklet implements TaskLet {

    private ReportRepository reportRepository;
    private FooAggregator fooAggregator;

    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext context) {
        byte[] data = fooAggregator.aggregate();
        reportRepository.getOne(reportId).setDataBytes(data);
    }
}
```

### Context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
    <bean id=fooWriter class="FooWriter" scope="step"
        p:fooAggregator-ref="fooAggregator"/>

    <bean id="fooAggregator" class="FooAggregator"/>

    <bean id="reportWritingTasklet" class="ReportWritingTasklet" scope="step"
        p:fooAggregator-ref="fooAggregator"/>

    <batch:job id="fooJob">
        <batch:step id="generateReport" next="assembleReport">
            <batch:chunk reader="fooReader" processor="fooProcessor" writer="fooWriter"/>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step id="assembleReport">
            <batch:tasklet class="ReportWritingTasklet"/>
        </batch:step>
     </batch:job>
</beans>
```

If I attempt to make the `FooAggregator` step-scoped I get the following exception as a root-cause

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type    [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98 implementing org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [FooAggregator] for property 'fooAggregator': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

This is because you're only meant to be able to scope certain things to the step.

How can I use the Execution context as a sink for my data chunks, bearing in mind there will be a lot of them and they will be very large?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this. It's not very Spring batch-y, but it meets my requirements.

Essentially, there is too much data to push into and out of the context. The solution has been to maintain the state in the writer itself, and to make it a `StepExecutionListener` that will save at the end of the `Step`, via a `TransactionCallback`.

### The Updated `Writer`

```
public class FooWriter extends StepExecutionListenerSupport implements ItemWriter<DataChunk> {

    private String reportId;
    private Map<Integer, byte[]> byteArrayMap = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();

    private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;
    private ReportRepository reportRepository;

    @Override
    public synchronized void write(List<? extends CaseChunk> caseChunks) throws Exception {
        caseChunks.stream().forEach(chunk -> {
            byteArrayMap.put(chunk.getPageNumber(), chunk.getBytes());
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        // No-op
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte[] byteArrayOutputStream : byteArrayMap.values()) {
            sb.append(new String(Base64.decode(byteArrayOutputStream)));
        }
        String encodedReportData = new String(Base64.encode(sb.toString().getBytes()));

        TransactionCallback<Report> transactionCallback = transactionStatus -> {
            Report report = reportRepository.getOne(this.reportId);
            report.setReportData(encodedReportData);
            reportRepository.save(report);
            return report;
        };

        // TransactionTemplate throws its own declared TransactionException, rethrows encountered RuntimeExceptions
        // and also Errors. Any problem writing the date kills the job, so it's OK to catch Throwable here instead
        // of trying to
        try {
            transactionTemplate.execute(transactionCallback);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            LOGGER.error("Error saving report data ID:[{}]", reportId);
            return ExitStatus.FAILED.addExitDescription(t);
        }
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }

}
```